# how to distinguish <br> inside <h5>?

Tags: xslt

could you help me with this problem please?

part of input xml:

```
<h5 class="Paragraf">
§ 113 a 114
<br/>
zrusen
</h5>
```

what would I like to have on output:

```
§ 113 a 114 -> A_Header_5
zrusen -> A_Header_5-Podnadpis
```

part of xslt condition which I created but it’s not doing what I want:

```
<xsl:when test="(self::h5) and not (child::br)">A_Header_5</xsl:when>                

<xsl:when test="(self::h5) and (child::br)">
  <xsl:if test="text()[1]">A_Header_5</xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="text()[2]">A_Header_5-Podnadpis</xsl:if>
</xsl:when>
```

unfortunately output with this xslt conditions looks this:

```
§ 113 a 114 -> A_Header_5A_Header_5-Podnadpis
zrusen -> A_Header_5A_Header_5-Podnadpis
```

Thank you

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly the same logic as in your post, but without a full _ Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_ it is hard to spot the root cause of your dissatisfaction with your code.

The following code iterates over all `text()` nodes and distinguishes on the basis of the existence of a following `<BR />` element.

**XSLT 1.0:**

```
<xsl:template match="h5">
    <xsl:for-each select="text()">
      <xsl:if test="."><xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping = "yes" select="concat(normalize-space(.),' -&gt; ')" /></xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="following-sibling::br">A_Header_5</xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::br)">A_Header_5-Podnadpis</xsl:if>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output:**

```
§ 113 a 114 -> A_Header_5
zrusen -> A_Header_5-Podnadpis
```

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry that I didn't mention this at the beginning. Problem is little bit complicated. We use xslt for Indesign file as the result. It means that you have xml as input then some transformation through xslt and Indesign file as a result. Xslt conditions mark up xml tags as Indesign paragraph styles. So my problem is, that I have <h5>§ 113 a 114<br/>zrusen</h5> on input and as a output I need to text "§ 113 a 114" will be mark up as A_Header_5 and text "zrusen" will be mark up as A_Header_5-Podnadpis.

Comment: I think that problem is somewhere inside conditions <xsl:if test="text()[1]">A_Header_5</xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="text()[2]">A_Header_5-Podnadpis</xsl:if> I want to xslt do this: find H5 if H5 contains BR then mark up text before BR as A_Header_5 and text after BR as A_Header_5-Podnadpis. Is it more understandable now? Thank you a lot.

Comment: @vyhruznakvyhruznakovic: "Is it more understandable now?" - hardly. Please add the real desired output to your question. As far as I understand you want to create elements like `<A_Header_5>§ 113 a 114</A_Header_5>`. Is that right? And there's still no [mcve].

Comment: Real desired output is a Indesign file. I've inserted it here, if it can help you: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QGq8F9q7ZmfzdIPeDo_TN5NAeqEuy2Le   you want to create elements like <A_Header_5>§ 113 a 114</A_Header_5><A_Header_5-Podnadpis>zrusen</A_Header_5-Podnadpis> = not exactly because as a result you will have Indesign file like is in drive.google file. I would like to add here example but it's not possible to add attachments. And you can't verify that xslt conditions make correct indesign paragraph styles as a result here (without transforming tool we are using).

Comment: @vyhruznakvyhruznakovic: Sorry. I don't know anything about _Indesign files_. The file on google drive is a binary file which is an unusual target format for XSLT. I can't help you with this.

Comment: Finally i found a solution: 
         <xsl:when test="self::h5">
          <xsl:for-each select="text()">
                <p>
                  <xsl:attribute name="class">
                        <xsl:choose>
                          <xsl:when test="position()=1">A_Header_5</xsl:when>
                             <xsl:otherwise>A_Header_5-Podnadpis</xsl:otherwise>
             </xsl:choose>
             </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
         </xsl:when>            
Thank you for your help.